# spark bulk insert millions of records into sql table of 400 columns GC limit exceeded

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bulkinsert, mssql-jdbc

I'm relatively new with spark scala and I am trying to bulk insert a dataframe containing millions of records into MS SQL. I am using [Azure sqldb spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark) to do the insertion but spark would crash (GC limit exceed or heartbeat not responding) before the actual insertion is made.

I have tried setting the increasing the memory, executors, timeout etc but still no able to make it write to the database. Normalising the table schema of 400 columns is not an option for me.

Appreciate any advice on how I can approach this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what value did you set for bulkCopyBatchSize?

Comment: @M.Alexandru my bulkCopyBatchSize is 1000, i added copymetadata for the table as well

Comment: Looks ok, what configuration do you have for executor-memory , num-executors, executor-cores ?